# Kotlin library was compiled with a newer Kotlin compiler and can't be read. Please update kotlin plugin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, authentication, compiler-errors

I am trying to add firebase authentication to my app. I am adding the following dependencies to gradle;

```
implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.3.1"))
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx")
implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.7.0")
```

After sync the gradle, I got an error like "Kotlin library {0} was compiled with a newer Kotlin compiler and can't be read. Please update kotlin plugin."[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbCkk.png)

How can I solve this? Thanks for your helps

Comment: Have you tried...updating your Kotlin plugin version?

Comment: Have you tried Ian's suggestion? Does that solve your problem?